# Continuously remove adjacent duplicate characters until there are none left

Tags: java

So I need to write a code where a string is entered and it prints out the string with no letters/char that are the same next to each other IF THEY ARE DUPLICATES! I got the code to work the first time I run through it BUT if I input a string like aabaarbarccrabmq, it will output brbarrabmq rather than getting rid of the r's, then the a's, and the b's following that. What do I do in order to have the string constantly update and have the loop keep running until there are absolutely 0 duplicates left?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  
{
    String input;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("The given string is: ");
    input = scan.nextLine();

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= input.length() - 2; counter++) 
    {
        if (counter != input.length() - 2)
        {
            if (input.charAt(counter - 1) != input.charAt(counter))
            {
                if (input.charAt(counter) != input.charAt(counter + 1))
                {
                    System.out.print(input.charAt(counter));
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (input.charAt(counter) != input.charAt(counter + 1))
            {
                System.out.print(input.charAt(counter));
                System.out.print(input.charAt(counter + 1));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"in order to have the string constantly update and have the loop keep running until there are absolutely 0 duplicates left"

what you are looking for is a while loop and instead of printing each character immediately, store them in a String and then print the string instead.

with that said your code should look sth like this:

```
boolean isAdjacentDuplicate(String str){
    //for loop
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    while(isAdjacentDuplicate(String str)){
        //your code here
    }
}
```

this can be improved further by returning the index of the duplicated char instead of boolean like so

```
    static int isAdjacentDuplicate(String str){
    
       //returns -1 if the string doesn't contain duplicated adjacent chars
       //returns index otherwise
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++){
            if(str.charAt(i-1)==str.charAt(i)||str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(i+1)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("enter the string: ");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
    
        int index = isAdjacentDuplicate(input);
        boolean isAdjacentDuplicate = index!=-1;
    
        //only loop when input still has duplicated adjacent char
        while(isAdjacentDuplicate){
            //delete duplicated char at index
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
            sb.deleteCharAt(index);
            //update the string
            input = sb.toString();
            //update
            index = isAdjacentDuplicate(input);
            isAdjacentDuplicate = index!=-1;
        }
    
        System.out.println(input);
    
    }
```

Comment: How would I update the string constantly and have it read, and would it work if the for loop was inside the while loop?

Comment: it would work if the for loop is inside the while loop. but as you can see from the updated answer, you need to iterate through the string to see if duplicated characters exist, using another for loop inside the while loop to get the index is unnecessary.